# Show a geo location using webview

Tags: android, dictionary, webview

I want to show a particular geo location on google maps. I can't use mapview / mapactivity.

Also I can't use action view intent

Can I use webview for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a url like this should work:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=47.404376,8.601478");
```

Replace 47.404376,8.601478 with your lat / long. Works in the browser, I guess on a mobile device it will open a mobile version of Google Maps.

Answer (score 3):

Check out google Static Map API
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=nl

You have to construct an url that displays a static image of a map (possible markers) of your location.
you can then download it and display it in an imageview.

```
String latitude= "45.838211";
String longitude = "9.334661";
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude+ "&zoom=10&size=400x400&sensor=false"
```

Comment: Thank you very much . This also fixes my problem. But i found the below more suiting my problem. Thanks again